# Web content is loading hidden

Tags: html, web

I'm not exactly sure how to describe quite the nature of the problem that I'm having. The source HTML files on the web server are loading in any browser except for firefox with an added tag argument `class="hidden"`. This argument for the tags that these show on are not present in the source HTML on the web server.

For example, `<p>` from the source file shows up as `<p class="hidden">` on chrome or opera. It shows as `<p class="">` on firefox. If we change `<p>` to `<p class=lead'>` in the source HTML file, chrome still loads it, but adds it into the argument, showing `<p class="lead hidden">` on inspect. It seems pretty well intent on making sure it loads hidden, but we don't know why. I can remove the `hidden` part from it in chrome's content inspector, and it will show, but even if I ctrl+shift+r in chrome, it doesn't load the proper code from the server, so these arbitrary bits of content are just hidden.

This is only happening from one location. All devices whose non-firefox browsers are having this issue are on the same network while this happens. Connections from other users seem to work properly. There doesn't seem to be anything I can find about anyone else having issues such as this and I'm hoping someone, here, can clarify what's happening here and how to rectify this bug.

Comment: Would you like to upload sample and image output, that would help understand it little better

Comment: Can the users having this problem load other websites? Or is this an issue with all sites? If it's the latter, then it's pretty clearly the router that's injecting something into their page. Is your site hosted on HTTPS? If not, then basically anyone *can* inject content.

Comment: All other sites load just fine. The isolation in this occurrence is anomalous to anyone who asks this question. I even switched the server's OS from Debian to CentOS and this still happens, and still only in this one network.

Comment: If it helps to know, the particular network whose clients are experiencing this issue is provisioned by AT&T. We don't know if this happens in other AT&T networks, we just know that this doesn't happen outside of this particular network, which has no special non-AT&T-default configurations set. The server is provisioned by OVH. This event even happens while clients connect via HTTPS. We still haven't had any progress in figuring out what is causing this.